# How do I use AVAssetWriter?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I’d like to take some video frames and encode them into a video. It looks like that’s exactly what `AVAssetWriter` was meant for, but no matter how I eyeball the docs and Google I can’t find any way to actually use it. From the docs it looks like I need an input (`AVAssetWriterInput`) to feed the writer from. Fine. But the `AVAssetWriterInput` class is abstract and the only subclass that I know of in 4.1 is `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` that requires a `AVAssetWriterInput` in its initializer…? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Nice work on search optimisation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah yes, I have to acquire an instance using `+[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:outputSettings:]`, see my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212) under a different question for a detailed code sample.