# iPhone programming - How to create a movie file from muti images and save it in iPod library?

Tags: objective-c, video-streaming, iphone, mjpeg

It is possible to do that?
please give me a hint.

Comment: A duplicate of [How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323), please search before posting new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would investigate [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/), specifically libavcodec - this will allow you to convert static images in to a movie file (assuming you can get it to compile for iOS).

As far as adding to the iPod library is concerned, you aint going to be able to do that - you can read from the library from within an iOS app, but not write to it.

Comment: Using FFmpeg is passé now that we have [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html).

Comment: @zoul - ok thanks, I've checked out the question that this is a duplicate of - you learn something every day ;-)