# AVAssetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer hangs when encoding video w/ audio on device

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avasset, avassetreader

After implementing the solution to encoding video (with audio) in this question, [Video Encoding using AVAssetWriter - CRASHES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191840/video-encoding-using-avassetwriter-crashes), I found that the code works correctly in the iPhone Simulator.  Unfortunately, certain videos fail to encode their audio while running on an actual iPhone 5 (and other devices).

For example, videos generated from the WWDC 2011 sample code RosyWriter (https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) do not completely encode because the function `-[AVAssetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer]` never returns.

The video buffers come in correctly, but as soon as it tries to copy the first audio CMSampleBufferRef, the call hangs.  When I try this on videos that come from other sources, like those recorded in the native iOS Camera app, the audio imports correctly.

This thread, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coreaudio-api/F4cqCu99nUI, makes note of the `copyNextSampleBuffer` function hanging when being used with AudioQueues, and suggests keeping the operations on a single thread.  I've tried keeping everything on a separate thread, on the main thread, but had no luck.

Did anyone else experience this and have a possible solution?

*EDIT*: It appears that videos generated from RosyWriter have their tracks reversed relative to videos from the native Camera app, i.e. audio stream as stream 0, and video stream as stream 1.

```
Stream #0:0(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 60 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2013-10-28 16:13:05
  handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Stream #0:1(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 8716 kb/s, 28.99 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
Metadata:
  rotate          : 90
  creation_time   : 2013-10-28 16:13:05
  handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

Not sure if this makes a difference to the AVAssetReader.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same issue. I have been reverse-engineering the RosyWriter to record my own videos, and when I try to encode/export them later, they 'sometimes' fail. It's very very inconsistent..

Comment: It seemed to be an issue with the way AVFoundation was encoding the audio track.  It's fixed in iOS8.  I'll add an answer.

Comment: Is there any recent development on this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was an AVFoundation bug in iOS7. It is now fixed in iOS8.

Comment: It's good news that it's fixed in iOS8, but for those of us who want to support earlier iOS-versions, it's still a problem :( I too have Audio as the first stream, video as the second, in my files. Did you find out if this had any significance to the error?

Comment: Not sure if it's related to the error, but the videos that record correctly in iOS8 now have video stream first, and audio stream second.

Comment: Did anybody find a workaround for this issue? Is there maybe a way to change the order of the streams when setting up the AssetWriter? I'd really like to be able to re-process a video I recorded before – also in iOS 7.

Comment: I tested this on iOS8 on my iPhone 5 and it is NOT WORKING. Works fine on simulator (NOT on the iPhone 5). Perhaps it works on iPhone 6?

Comment: I'm seeing copyNextBuffer occasionally hang on iOS 9.3.3 as well. For me, it's occurring sporadically with an AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput with an asset that has 5 audio tracks, all with non-empty time ranges. Anyone else still seeing this?

Comment: Still a problem on iOS 13, new hardware.

Answer (score 4):

I was still experiencing this issue on iOS 9.3.2, and the thing that resolved it was making sure that the `AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput*` was initially set with options rather than `nil` when calling `-[AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput assetReaderAudioMixOutputWithAudioTracks]`.

Example:

```
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                                    nil];

// create an AVAssetReaderOutput for the audio tracks
NSArray* audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput* _audioReaderOutput = [AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput assetReaderAudioMixOutputWithAudioTracks:audioTracks audioSettings:outputSettings];
```

This prevented later calls to `-[AVAssetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer]` from hanging when they otherwise were doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Check the time range on the audio tracks using something like this:

```
NSLog(@"audioTrack timeRange: %lld, %lld", audioTrack.timeRange.start.value, audioTrack.timeRange.duration.value);
```

Empty time ranges (0, 0) can cause copyNextSampleBuffer() to hang.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have videos with a non-empty time range that still fail.

Comment: Did you check each individual track in the video file?

Comment: Yes.  There is only one video track and one audio track in the video file, and they both have non-empty time ranges.

Answer (score -1):

This is a a hardware specific issue. I tested it on the simulator, iPhone5, and iPhone 6. The problem occurs 100% with certain video files, but ONLY on the iPhone 5. I can't speak for the iPhone 5S though. iOS8 does NOT fix this issue. The fix may be having to limit your iPhone 5 users from certain features. Another work around is to have the user select a video from their camera roll, thus forcing Apple's special compression on it - and baptizing that video into a format that the iPhone 5 hardware can work with.

Comment: Occurring years later on all sorts of devices.