# AVAssetWriter equivalent for IOS < 4.1

Tags: iphone, video-encoding

I read this posting about writing a movie using AVAssetWriter:

[How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212)

What is the equivalent way to generate a movie in IOS 4.0 and earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way, at least not using the iOS SDK.
The ability to do this was added in 4.0

You would have to use some 3rd party solution, maybe [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org)?

Answer (score 0):

I decided this was too much work and I'm now using AVFoundation.  My app will require IOS 4.1.