# iPhone merger UIImage and CAF Audio to AV file

Tags: iphone, image, audio, avfoundation, movie

I want to merger an image file and an audio file.

I have UIImage object in which I have my image.
I have also CAF audio recording of 4-5 seconds.

Now, I would like to create a movie file with image repeating for the length of audio.

Using which class/methods can I do this? Any Idea?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question should help you:

[How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie)

THe only difference is that in the question they use several UIImages, you only need to repeat the same one.

Good Luck