# Why does my movie from UIImages gets distorted?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, export, avfoundation

I'm using [zoul's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212) to export UIImage array as a movie. But my frames all turns out distorted. Here's the original image:

[image: original image]

Here's a similar distortion example:
[image: similar distortion example]

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327847/output-from-avassetwriter-uiimages-written-to-video-distorted) that it has something to do with aspect ratio, but there's no explanation on how to fix it.

Comment: I know that this is because of multiply by 16, Bu how to solve this issue ? I have images with 1080*1980 any suggestion ?

Comment: @DipenChudasama downscale to a size where the width is a multiple of 16

Comment: Thanks @Cbas I was doing same :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After a lot of experiments with different image sizes, and with the help of this [article](http://www.kenstone.net/fcp_homepage/compressor_h-264_movies_fcp.html), I've got to the conclusion that the width of the images must be a multiple of 16.

Comment: Wasted many hours wondering what was going on ... this was the key!

Comment: This finally did it! Thanks so much.

Comment: thank you so much! i was struggling with this for hours! this fixed it!

Comment: Do we know why this is the case?

Comment: Great great great !!!  guys the best size is 1024 x 1024 , just convert you image to 1024

Comment: BTW - width:height vs height:width matters. I thought 1080:1920 would work but its the width that needs to be a multiple of 16 - had to downscale to 1024:1820

Comment: @Cbas how did you down scale? I have some images in an array. Shall I draw them in bitamp context forcing the width to be a multiple of 16 and at the  same time maintaining the aspect ratio of height parameter?

Comment: Okay, but what do I do if I really need that 1080x1920 image resolution? It's absolutely a requirement for my purposes, because I have a FullHD video, I take the last frame out of it, generate a 3 second video from this frame, and then combine those two videos, and since I want to preserve the best quality, I need that 1080x1920 image.

Comment: @xinatanil Is it a portrait? Maybe try to rotate it, export, and then rotate again?
Or using a 1072x1,905.7778 size?

Comment: @Geva I went with 1008x1792 image size, which is a viable solution for me, but my inner perfectionist is still mad with the fact that I cannot generate a 1080x1920 image properly from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

For those still doing the journey in 2020,  and getting distortion in their movies because its not width 16px

change

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata,
                                             width, height,
                                             8, 4 * width,
                                             rgbColorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
```

to

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata,
                                             width, height,
                                             8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pxbuffer),
                                             rgbColorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
```

Credit to @Bluedays [Output from AVAssetWriter (UIImages written to video) distorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327847/output-from-avassetwriter-uiimages-written-to-video-distorted/60663208#comment114782685_60663208)

Answer (score 2):

I'v encountered this problem too, and I found the reason is the image's size is not the multiple of 16, you can change the size and have a try.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. Do you mean the image size does not *actually* have to be 16 - and that you merely have to specify the width? If so, where do you specify the width?