# UIImage Distortion from UIGraphicsBeginImageContext with larger files (pixel formats, codecs?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, uigraphicscontext

I'm cropping UIImages with a UIBezierPath using UIGraphicsContext:

```
CGSize thumbnailSize = CGSizeMake(54.0f, 45.0f); // dimensions of UIBezierPath
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(thumbnailSize, NO, 0);
[path addClip];
[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, originalImage.size.height/-3, thumbnailSize.width, originalImage.size.height)];
UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But for some reason my images are getting stretched vertically (everything looks slightly long and skinny), and this effect is stronger the bigger my `originalImage` is. I'm sure the originalImages are perfectly fine before I do these operations (I've checked)

My images are all 9:16 (say 72px wide by 128px tall) if that matters.

I've seen UIGraphics creates a bitmap with an "ARGB 32-bit integer pixel format using host-byte order"; and I'll admit a bit of ignorance when it comes to pixel formats, but felt this MAY be relevant because I'm not sure if that's the same pixel format I use to encode the picture data.

No idea how relevant this is but here is the FULL processing pipeline:
I'm capturing using AVFoundation and I set my photoSettings as

```
NSDictionary *photoSettings = @{AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264};
```

capturing using `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:..` then turning it into NSData using `[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];` then downsizing into thumbnail by creating a `CGDataProviderRefWithCFData` and converting to `CGImageRef` using `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` and getting a UIImage from that.

Later, I once again turn it into NSData using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 0.7)` so I can store. And finally when I'm ready to display I call my own method detailed on top `[self maskImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] toPath:_thumbnailPath]` and display it on a UIImageView and set `contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

If the method I'm using to mask the UIImage with the UIBezierPath is fine, I may end up explicitly setting the photoOutput settings with `[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil]` and the I can probably use something like [how to convert a CVImageBufferRef to UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152259/how-to-convert-a-cvimagebufferref-to-uiimage) and change a lot of my code... but I really rather not do that unless completely necessary since, as I've mentioned, I really don't know much about video encoding / all these graphical, low level objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, originalImage.size.height/-3, thumbnailSize.width, originalImage.size.height)];
```

is a problem. You are drawing `originalImage` but you specify the width of `thumbnailSize.width` and the height of `originalImage`. This messes up the image's aspect ratio.

You need a width and a height based on the same image size. Pick one as needed to maintain the proper aspect ratio.

Comment: *facepalm*....
Just came from dealing with another distortion issue (similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691646/why-does-my-movie-from-uiimages-gets-distorted?rq=1) so of course I convince myself that this MUST be an issue with my image processing pipeline...

Comment: Things like this make me simultaneously love and hate programming for (a) not being as hard as I thought it was.. but (b) being all too easy to make a careless error (like calling the wrong variable) that messes everything up