# Recording Auido and Video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is there any sample example which demonstrates recording audio and video simultaneously using AVAssetWriter?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a few examples where AVAssetWriter is used:

- [RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [StopNGo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StopNGo/Introduction/Intro.html)

There is a Keynote Presentation where AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter are looked in to titled [Advanced Media Manipulation with AV Foundation](http://www.slideshare.net/invalidname/advanced-media-manipulation-with-av-foundation)

Also check out this SO Post: [How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212)