# Save video to iPhone library using AVfoundation framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad

I am using `AVfoundation` framework to get video camera frames at real time and then modifying those frames using one algorithm(which gives new modified image).

now I want all modified frames to be save as a video to iPhone library. I found a way to save video for input(original) frames using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` but not for modified frames.

Is there any way to save modified frames to iPhone Library as a video ??

Answer (score 0):

> [UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW41)
>
> Adds the movie at the specified path to the user’s Camera Roll album.

Comment: @Alexandru - this function need video url path which unfortunately I don't have because I am doing real time camera operation on the frames and want to save all those frames to camera roll album. so I am looking for custom url path which will have the all modified images.

Comment: finally I have found soln on thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212 thanks Alexandru for replying.