# Converting series of images to video-iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, video

I want to convert a series of images to video in iphone

Can anybody suggest a method or framework for this.

Thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best place to start is with the AVFoundation framework.  A similar question, with an extremely detailed and helpful answer, can be found here:
[How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212)

A combination of `AVAssetWriter` and `CVPixelBufferRef` should get you where you need to go.