# How to generate video file with iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie)

I need to generate video file with iPhone SDK, currently thinking of images, that placed in UIView in needed order and then assemble them in one final video, but I can't find way to do this.