# iOS: create a video and save it where?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I am capturing a video on an iOS device using this: [How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212)

Is there any way to get the video out of the device to my MAC? (I want to use the simulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always browse the simulator folders saved on your Mac. You can find them under:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[OS version]/Applications/[appGUID]/
```

Once you find your app folder, just take the file saved by the app.