# iphone: when trying to export a image as a movie, the movie is corrupted

Tags: ios, iphone

i'm trying to export a movie from a single image.
something along the lines of [How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie).

i tried many varitents, but i keep getting corrupted videos. (color and image are all wrong).
any idea anyone?
thanks

CODE:

```
- (void)writeImageAsMovie:(UIImage*)image toPath:(NSString*)path size:(CGSize)size duration:(int)duration 
{
NSFileManager *localFileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSError *error = nil;
[localFileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
NSLog(@"Write Started");

AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                          error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];
AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                    assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                    outputSettings:videoSettings];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                 assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil];
NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
[videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

//Start a session:
[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

//Write samples:
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = [self newPixelBufferFromCGImage:image.CGImage andSize:image.size];
[adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];
[adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:CMTimeMake(duration-1, 2)];

//Finish the session:
[writerInput markAsFinished];
[videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMake(duration, 2)];
[videoWriter finishWriting];
```

}

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef) newPixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image andSize:(CGSize) size
{
 NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;

CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width,
                                      size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options, 
                                      &pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                             size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace, 
                                             kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
NSParameterAssert(context);
//CGContextConcatCTM(context, frameTransform);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), 
                                       CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

return pxbuffer;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI here, but I am seeing this same error in the simulator when the width of the video being encoded is odd. For example, on a 16x16 image there is no error, but the error shows up for a 17x16 movie. It does not show up for a 18x18 movie, so I think it has something to do with the process of H264 encoding expecting input that is multiples of 4. Also, it only seems to be a problem in the simulator.