# iOS thumbnail issue with saved video to camera roll

Tags: ios, avfoundation

We have an issue where video generated by our application and saved to camera roll (from user action) will show as black thumbnail on the iOS Photo Gallery instead of a thumbnail of a frame. Once you select the video it will play without any issues on the iOS device or any other device (export to your mac or pc...).

The issue does not occur on the iPhone simulator, only on iOS devices..

We generate the video using AVFoundation (very similiar to this [How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212))

We then combine the video with an mp3 file using AVMutableVideoComposition. If I extract all frame of video, first frame is not black.

The thumbnail in the Photo Gallery will show as a black square, no time span (on iOS4) shown on the thumbnail. We save the video to camera roll using UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum ...

We have changed the video compression type and settings multiple times with no luck. The output is a H264 QuickTimeMovie.

Any ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue to this. I also use AVFoundation to generate a video and save to camera roll, however instead of a black square for a thumbnail, mine will show a beige square with "mp4" baked in.

Comment: I'm also seeing a similar issue - playback is fine but the thumbnail appears black in the camera roll.