# Animating large sized images

Tags: iphone

I want to play an animation of around 120 images, each of a large size and dimensions (640 x 960) using
 [UIImageView setAnimationImages:]
I guess it won't be right approach to do this, because it is going to consume a lot of device RAM at runtime. Please suggest me any other approach to perform such animation in more efficient way in terms of memory management. I can't make video out of the images coz the images won't be same every time, they depend on user's action.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you need is to indeed make a video from the images, but programmatically after they have been generated according to the user actions. After if has been built, you'll be able to play it without memory problems.

[Here you have an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie) that explains how to do it.