# Most efficient way for displaying procedurally generated video frames on iOS

Tags: ios, video, ios6, xamarin.ios

I need to display a sequence procedurally generated images as video sequence preferably with built-in controls (controls would be nice to have, but no requirement) and I'm just looking for a bit of guidance of which API to use. There seem to be a number of options  but I'm not sure which one is the best suited to my needs. [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), Core Video, Core Animation, OpenGL ES or something else?

Targetting just iOS 6 and up would be no problem if that helps.

**Update**: I'd prefer something that would allow me to display the video frames directly rather than writing them to a temporary movie.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie

Comment: Sure it does. But if possible I'd like to avoid encoding the video data into temporary movie.

Comment: If you are simply displaying them I would throw them all into an array and simply change the images using a timer. Is there a frame rate requirement?

Comment: Maximum Frame Rate would 50fps.

Comment: The easiest solution is to add the image sequentially into an NSMutableArray and then cycle through that array with a timer set at 50ms. Obviously the size of the images will play a huge role in the performance though.

Comment: What did you decided to use? I'm searching for a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the animationImages property of UIImageView. This may do what you are looking for. Basically you would store all of your images into this array so it can handle the animation for you. [UIImageView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: The issue you may come across is cache size (running out of avail mem) since I believe animationImages holds all the images in memory for quick access. It's a very convenient method but without knowing your exact file size requirements it's very hard to offer a suggestion other than manually looping through and changing the UIImageView's image property at the rate you wish. Best of luck!