# Create CMSampleBufferRef using a UIImage

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, cmsamplebufferref

How to create a CMSampleBufferRef using a UIImage,i need to add text on video frames while recording.
*Please do not tell me to use PixelBuffer.

Comment: Look at the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475737/convert-uiimage-to-cmsamplebufferref

Comment: Give some more detail description about your requirements to get maximum answers.

Comment: @json I want to add time indicator text on video while recording it.

Comment: Did you got anything regarding this video recording?