# Any way to convert UIImage to CMSampleBuffer on Swift?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, ocr, avcapture, cmsamplebuffer

I'm using ABBYY OCR SDK and it's great at text recognition direct from camera from  CMSampleBuffer in:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

They've got another SDK for image recognition using which however will increase the app size for a couple of dozen Mb.

So wondering if there is any way to convert UIImage to CMSampleBuffer.

Comment: Why not just pass the sample buffer directly to the other sdk? I can't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to recognise text from UIImage (from photo library)  not from camera. And do not want to use second framework to do it

Comment: I'd suggest checking carefully the sdk. Since it is almost 90% likely that its not using a sample buffer, but instead its internally changing it into some kind of processable data. Does the sdk provide any other kind of available inputs?

Comment: the only method they use is: grab CMSampleBuffer and return text (or error)

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475737/convert-uiimage-to-cmsamplebufferref

Comment: Yeah, I saw it. but could not reproduce the code on swift.. Used Several solutions but the only thing I achieved is leaking memory.. anyway, Thanks!