# Merge images and videos to make a complete movie

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am working on application in which I am suppose to implement the functionality where the user can merge images and videos to make a complete movie.

I know how to merge videos only using `AVMutableComposition`, but how to merge images in it ?
We can make a video from the images using `AVAssetWriter` but i guess we cannot add videos in it...

Can anyone help me out to sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`AVMutableComposition`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/Reference/Reference.html). To create the video track from your UIImage use [`AVAssetWriter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Take a look at this Beautiful Link : 
[Create movie from array of images.](http://www.developers-life.com/create-movie-from-array-of-images.html)

This is the [Best Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742212/1603072).

Comment: NOTE: Safari complains about the `Create movie from array of images.` link you have saying it's a deceptive and sends via many redirects.