# iOS: core animation to video

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation

I'm making a photo gallery app. I use the photos as slides and shows them one by one with transactions made by `core animation`.
Now I need to turn this process in to a video so that I can share it on Youtube, but I don't know where to start or which reference should I read.

Answer (score 0):

To make video in iphone you can [AVAssetWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742212/641062).

Also have a look this [post](http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-screen-capture-view/1038). You can capture your animation as images and make the video.

Answer (score -1):

The AVAsset Apple APIs is used to do this sort of thing is. But be warned, it is not easy to use. If you would like to check out a working example Xcode project, see [AVDecodeEncode](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVDecodeEncode). This example shows decoding from h.264 and then encoding the result back to h.264. You could write all you own code to do this, but just be aware that it is not for the faint of heart.