# Screen Capture in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm working on a project and we would like to be able to record a `UIView`. The idea I had and implemented would be to take continuous screen shots and store them on disc and then after the `UIView` is done combine all the images to make a movie. Right now I'm using `UIImage` to combine and make a movie. This seems like a pretty slow process and I've read some things online, like RecordMyScreen project, but that uses private APIs like IOSurface and so on. I'm just wondering if theres a quick way to take screen shots. I would require to take about 25 a second. Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.captureView.frame.size, YES, 0.0);
// CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// [self.captureView.layer renderInContext:context];
[self.captureView drawViewHierarchyInRect:weakSelf.captureView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage* screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSLog(@"saving image");
[self saveImageToFolder:self.tempFolderPath image:screenShot];
```

this is in an `NSOperationBlock` to be performed in the background. Saving to disc is also done on another thread.

I know that `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` takes `CVPixelBufferRef` to create the movie so I'm not sure if theres a way to get that directly from the `UIView`?

Anyway any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Got a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New API has been added since iOS 7, that should provide efficient way of getting snapshot

`snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`: renders the view into a `UIView` with unmodifiable content

`resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets` : same thing, but with resizable insets

`drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates`: : same thing if you need all subviews to be drawn too (like labels, buttons...)

You can use the `UIView` returned for any UI effect, or render in into an image like you did if you need to export.

You can also try this, it worked for me.

```
- (UIImage *) screenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```