# Generated malformed video from a normal CGImageRef image after appliesPreferredTrackTransform setted

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to get image from a video, then use this image to generate a still movie
The first step works well, but the second step generated a malformed video after I set appliesPreferredTrackTransform=true

normal image extracted from the video
[image: normal image extracted from the video]
malformed video generated from the image
[image: malformed video generated from the image]

How did this come? A normal image generated a malformed video?
besides, if I put the GenerateMovieFromImage.generateMovieWithImage block in #2
the app will crash at CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height), image);

I did as below(in swift):

```
    var asset: AVAsset  = AVAsset.assetWithURL(self.tmpMovieURL!) as AVAsset
    var imageGen: AVAssetImageGenerator =  AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    var time: CMTime = CMTimeMake(0, 60)
    imageGen.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    imageGen.generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes( [ NSValue(CMTime:time) ], completionHandler: {

        (requestTime, image, actualTime, result, error) -> Void in
            if result == AVAssetImageGeneratorResult.Succeeded {



                ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, metadata: nil, completionBlock: {
                    (nsurl, error) in
                       // #2                    
                })

                 GenerateMovieFromImage.generateMovieWithImage(image, completionBlock:{
                        (genMovieURL) in
                        handler(genMovieURL)

                })
```

The GenerateMovieFromImage.generateMovieWithImage was from [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212)

```
+ (void)generateMovieWithImage:(CGImageRef)image completionBlock:(GenerateMovieWithImageCompletionBlock)handler
{

NSLog(@"%@", image);

NSString *path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: [@"tmpgen" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"  ] ];

NSURL *videoUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path] ) {
    NSError *error;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"removeitematpath %@ error :%@", path, error);
    }
}


// TODO: image need to rotate programly, not in hand
int width = (int)CGImageGetWidth(image);
int height = (int)CGImageGetHeight(image);

NSError *error = nil;
AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:videoUrl
                               fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                          error:&error];
NSParameterAssert(videoWriter);

NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                               nil];
AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                    assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                    outputSettings:videoSettings] ; //retain should be removed if ARC


NSParameterAssert(writerInput);
NSParameterAssert([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]);
[videoWriter addInput:writerInput];

AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
                                                 assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                 sourcePixelBufferAttributes:nil ];

//    2) Start a session:
NSLog(@"start session");

[videoWriter startWriting];
[videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero]; //use kCMTimeZero if unsure


dispatch_queue_t mediaInputQueue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);
[writerInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:mediaInputQueue usingBlock:^{

     if ([writerInput isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {


         //    3) Write some samples:

         // Or you can use AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor.
         // That lets you feed the writer input data from a CVPixelBuffer
         // that’s quite easy to create from a CGImage.


         CVPixelBufferRef sampleBuffer = [self newPixelBufferFromCGImage:image];

         if (sampleBuffer) {
             CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(150,30);
            [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:sampleBuffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];
            [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:sampleBuffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
             CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
         }
     }


    //    4) Finish the session:

    [writerInput markAsFinished];
    [videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(5, 30.0) ] ; //optional can call finishWriting without specifiying endTime
    // [videoWriter finishWriting]; //deprecated in ios6
    NSLog(@"to finnish writing");

    [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"%@",videoWriter);
        NSLog(@"finishWriting..");

        handler(videoUrl);

        ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] completionBlock: ^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
            if( error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum error: %@" , error);
            }

        }];
    }]; //ios 6.0+

}];





}


+ (CVPixelBufferRef) newPixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef)image
{
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         nil];
CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;


CGSize frameSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image) );

NSLog(@"width:%f", frameSize.width);
NSLog(@"height:%f", frameSize.height);



CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, frameSize.width,
                                      frameSize.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options,
                                      &pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);
NSParameterAssert(pxdata != NULL);

CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, frameSize.width,
                                             frameSize.height, 8, 4*frameSize.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                             (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
                                             );

NSParameterAssert(context);



CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height), image);
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

return pxbuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput sourcePixelBufferAttributes:sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary ];
```

I find your problem:

```
(requestTime, image, actualTime, result, error) -> Void in
     if result == AVAssetImageGeneratorResult.Succeeded {

        let img : UIImage = UIImage(CGImage: image)! // retain 
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img,nil,nil,nil) // synchron

        GenerateMovieFromImage.generateMovieWithImage(image, completionBlock:{
                (genMovieURL) in
                        handler(genMovieURL)

         })
```

I check all works. If  you still have problem, then problem is in ur device.

Comment: It does not work, too, I'm trying to use my ipad to test whether is my iphone's problem. But I think maybe the problem is the transform matrix of AVFoundation or CoreGraphics.

Comment: Add this check: if (![videoWriter startWriting])  and check appendPixelBuffer result.  You can see error like this videoWriter.error.

Comment: all return yes, no error logged. And I tried but cannot get the program run on my iPad(it can't jailbreak)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have get some improvement.

In function (CVPixelBufferRef) newPixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef)image

change :

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                     nil];
```

to:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:4*frameSize.width], kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAlignmentKey,nil];
```

The photo is **not malformed**. but it seems it's been scaled in its y-cord to 0.5 as its normal height!

I'm still working to solve this problem.

---

update:

I've totally solved this problem:
This is because the attribute [transform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriterInput_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetWriterInput/transform) and [preformTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetTrack/preferredTransform)

```
The transform specified in the track’s storage container as the preferred
```

transformation of the visual media data for display purposes.

This means that the real orientation of a video file may be not as you see when playing.

The AVPlayer use the transform in this file to play. However, the generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes will ignore this attribute. and get a landscape(for example) picture. so, will need to set the transform back to match to original video file.

Just add this before

```
writerInput.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2) ;
```

before

```
AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput
                                       assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                       outputSettings:videoSettings] ; //retain should be removed if ARC
```

will solve this problem.

Comment: Solved by multiple height with 2, but I don't know why:  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, frameSize.width,
                                             frameSize.height*2, 8, 4*frameSize.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                             (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
                                             );   CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, frameSize.width, frameSize.height*2), image);

Comment: The video encoders you're using may have width restrictions, e.g. width must be divisible two or four. Have you tried changing your width?

Answer (score 1):

I too got this error when I tried to create a video with an array of images and music file. It's because of the video frame ratio. So check the frame for video composition. For your reference: http://size43.com/jqueryVideoTool.html