# How to merge a *Single Image* with a video

Tags: swift, uiimage, buffer, avassetwriter, avmutablecomposition

I am trying to combine a single video with a single image. **This is not trying to combine many images into a single video** such as

- [create movie from [UIImage], Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470154/create-movie-from-uiimage-swift)
- [How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie)
- [Make movie file with picture Array and song file, using AVAsset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061092/make-movie-file-with-picture-array-and-song-file-using-avasset)

I am using `AVMutableComposition` to combine tracks. My app has the ability to combine videos and images (but as it stands, the videos combining is fine!) I attempt to use `AVAssetWriter` to turn a single image into a video (I believe this is where my problem is but not 100% sure). Then I save that to the app (`documents directory`). From there, I access it inside my merger, and combine a video and the image that now has turned into the video.

*Flow*:

User selects image ->

Image into AVAssetWriter to change to video ->

Merge a video I already have preset with the video ->

Result: Make 1 video from the image selected and preset video.

The problem with what I have: My code is providing a blank space where the image inside the video should be. As in, the ImageConverter file I have, will convert it to video, but I will only SEE the very LAST frame as the image, while every other frame is transparent, as if the picture is not there. So if I convert the image to a video for 5 seconds (let's say at 30 frames/sec) then I will see blank space for (30*5)-1 frames and then that last frame, the picture will finally appear. I am just looking for guidance on how to make a single image into a video **OR** combine a video and an image together WITHOUT converting the image into a video. Thanks!

**Merge Files here**

```
func merge() {
    if let firstAsset = controller.firstAsset, secondAsset = self.asset {

        // 1 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
        let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

        let firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                                     preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        do {
            try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTime(seconds: 8, preferredTimescale: 600)),
                                           ofTrack: firstAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] ,
                                           atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch _ {
            print("Failed to load first track")
        }

        do {
            //HERE THE TIME IS 0.666667, BUT SHOULD BE 0
            print(CMTimeGetSeconds(secondAsset.duration), CMTimeGetSeconds(firstTrack.timeRange.duration))
            try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration),
                                            ofTrack: secondAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0],
                                            atTime: firstTrack.timeRange.duration)
        } catch _ {
            print("Failed to load second track")
        }
        do {
            try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(CMTime(seconds: 8+CMTimeGetSeconds(secondAsset.duration), preferredTimescale: 600), firstAsset.duration),
                                           ofTrack: firstAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] ,
                                           atTime: firstTrack.timeRange.duration+secondTrack.timeRange.duration)
        } catch _ {
            print("failed")
        }

        // 3 - Audio track
        if let loadedAudioAsset = controller.audioAsset {
            let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: 0)
            do {
                try audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration),
                                               ofTrack: loadedAudioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] ,
                                               atTime: kCMTimeZero)
            } catch _ {
                print("Failed to load Audio track")
            }
        }

        // 4 - Get path
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
        let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
        let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo.mov")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: savePath)
        _ = try? NSFileManager().removeItemAtURL(url)

        // 5 - Create Exporter
        print("exporting")
        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else { return }
        exporter.outputURL = url
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
        exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = false
        exporter.videoComposition = mainComposition

        // 6 - Perform the Export
        controller.currentlyEditing = true
        exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { _ in
                print("done")
                self.controller.currentlyEditing = false
                self.controller.merged = true
                self.button.blurView.superview?.hidden = true
                self.controller.player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(AVPlayerItem(URL: url))
                self.controller.firstAsset = AVAsset(URL: url)
            }
        }
    }
}
func exportDidFinish(session: AVAssetExportSession) {
    if session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed {
        print(session.error)
    }
    if session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed {
        print("succed")
    }
}
```

**Convert Image Here**

```
class MyConverter: NSObject {

    var image:UIImage!

    convenience init(image:UIImage) {
        self.init()
        self.image = image
    }

    var outputURL: NSURL {
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
        let savePath = (documentDirectory as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-pic.mov")
        return getURL(savePath)
    }

    func getURL(path:String) -> NSURL {
        let movieDestinationUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        _ = try? NSFileManager().removeItemAtURL(movieDestinationUrl)
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        return url
    }

    func build(completion:() -> Void) {
        guard let videoWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(URL: outputURL, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie) else {
            fatalError("AVAssetWriter error")
        }
        let outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey : NSNumber(float: Float(image.size.width)), AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(float: Float(image.size.height))]

        guard videoWriter.canApplyOutputSettings(outputSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else {
            fatalError("Negative : Can't apply the Output settings...")
        }

        let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: outputSettings)
        let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB), kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: NSNumber(float: Float(image.size.width)), kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: NSNumber(float: Float(image.size.height))]
        let pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)

        if videoWriter.canAddInput(videoWriterInput) {
            videoWriter.addInput(videoWriterInput)
        }

        if videoWriter.startWriting() {
            videoWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)
            assert(pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool != nil)
        }

        let media_queue = dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", nil)

        videoWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue(media_queue, usingBlock: { () -> Void in
            var appendSucceeded = true
            //Time HERE IS ZERO, but in Merge file, it is 0.66667
            let presentationTime = CMTimeMake(0, 600)

            var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
            let status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool!, &pixelBuffer)

            if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer where status == 0 {
                let managedPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, 0)

                let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer)
                let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, Int(self.image.size.width), Int(self.image.size.height), 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(managedPixelBuffer), rgbColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)

                CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(self.image.size.width), CGFloat(self.image.size.height)))


                CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height), self.image.CGImage)

                CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, 0)

                appendSucceeded =     pixelBufferAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
            } else {
                print("Failed to allocate pixel buffer")
                appendSucceeded = false
            }
            if !appendSucceeded {
                print("append failed")
            }
            videoWriterInput.markAsFinished()
            videoWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in
                print("FINISHED!!!!!")
                completion()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have found out that if I do a `print(presentationTime)` INSIDE the ImageConverter it prints 0, and then print the time of the duration inside the merger, I get 0.666667

**Note:** No answers yet, but I will continuously be making this question a bounty until I find an answer or someone else helps me! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right, so I actually dealt with this problem a while ago. The issue is indeed with how you are creating the video from the picture. What you need to do is add the pixel buffer at time zero, and then AGAIN at the end, otherwise you will end up with an empty video until the very last frame, like you are experiencing.

The following code will be my best attempt to update your code. At the very end I will post my solution which is in Objective-C in case it helps anyone else.

```
func build(completion:() -> Void) {
    guard let videoWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(URL: outputURL, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie) else {
        fatalError("AVAssetWriter error")
    }

    // This might not be a problem for you but width HAS to be divisible by 16 or the movie will come out distorted... don't ask me why. So this is a safeguard
    let pixelsToRemove: Double = fmod(image.size.width, 16)
    let pixelsToAdd: Double = 16 - pixelsToRemove
    let size: CGSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width + pixelsToAdd, image.size.height)

    let outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoWidthKey : NSNumber(float: Float(size.width)), AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(float: Float(size.height))]

    guard videoWriter.canApplyOutputSettings(outputSettings, forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else {
        fatalError("Negative : Can't apply the Output settings...")
    }

    let videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: outputSettings)
    let sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB), kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: NSNumber(float: Float(size.width)), kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: NSNumber(float: Float(size.height))]
    let pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourcePixelBufferAttributesDictionary)

    if videoWriter.canAddInput(videoWriterInput) {
        videoWriter.addInput(videoWriterInput)
    }

    if videoWriter.startWriting() {
        videoWriter.startSessionAtSourceTime(kCMTimeZero)
        assert(pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool != nil)
    }

    // For simplicity, I'm going to remove the media queue you created and instead explicitly wait until I can append since i am only writing one pixel buffer at two different times

    var pixelBufferCreated = true
    var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
    let status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool!, &pixelBuffer)

    if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer where status == 0 {
        let managedPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, 0)

        let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer)
        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, Int(size.width), Int(size.height), 8, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(managedPixelBuffer), rgbColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)

        CGContextClearRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(size.width), CGFloat(size.height)))

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height), self.image.CGImage)

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, 0)
    } else {
        print("Failed to allocate pixel buffer")
        pixelBufferCreated = false
    }

    if (pixelBufferCreated) {
        // Here is where the magic happens, we have our pixelBuffer it's time to start writing

        // FIRST - add at time zero
        var appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: kCMTimeZero];
        if (!appendSucceeded) {
            // something went wrong, up to you to handle. Should probably return so the rest of the code is not executed though
        }
        // SECOND - wait until the writer is ready for more data with an empty while
        while !writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData {} 

        // THIRD - make a CMTime with the desired length of your picture-video. I am going to arbitrarily make it 5 seconds here
        let frameTime: CMTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1) // 5 seconds

        // FOURTH - add the same exact pixel to the end of the video you are creating
        appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.appendPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: frameTime];
        if (!appendSucceeded) {
            // something went wrong, up to you to handle. Should probably return so the rest of the code is not executed though
        }

        videoWriterInput.markAsFinished() {
            videoWriter.endSessionAtSourceTime(frameTime)
        }
        videoWriter.finishWritingWithCompletionHandler { () -> Void in
            if videoWriter.status != .Completed {
                // Error writing the video... handle appropriately 
            } else {
                print("FINISHED!!!!!")
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

## How I managed to do this in Obj-C

Note: I had to make some edits to make this standalone, so this method will return a string holding the path the video **WILL BE** written to. It is returned before the video writing finishes so it *may* be possible to access it before it is ready if you are not careful

```
-(NSString *)makeMovieFromImageData:(NSData *)imageData {
    NSError *error;
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


    // width has to be divisible by 16 or the movie comes out distorted... don't ask me why
    double pixelsToRemove = fmod(image.size.width, 16);

    double pixelsToAdd = 16 - pixelsToRemove; 

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image.size.width+pixelsToAdd, image.size.height);

    BOOL hasFoundValidPath = NO;
    NSURL *tempFileURL;
    NSString *outputFile;

    while (!hasFoundValidPath) {

        NSString *guid = [[NSUUID new] UUIDString];
        outputFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"picture_%@.mp4", guid];

        NSString *outputDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSTemporaryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *tempPath = [outputDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:outputFile];

        // Will fail if destination already has a file
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:tempPath]) {
            continue;
        } else {
            hasFoundValidPath = YES;
        }
        tempFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempPath];
    }


    // Start writing
    AVAssetWriter *videoWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:tempFileURL
                                                           fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
                                                              error:&error];

    if (error) {
       // handle error
    }

    NSDictionary *videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt:size.height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                                   nil];

    AVAssetWriterInput* writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                         outputSettings:videoSettings];

    NSDictionary *bufferAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];

    AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor *adaptor = [AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor assetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptorWithAssetWriterInput:writerInput
                                                                                                                     sourcePixelBufferAttributes:bufferAttributes];
    if ([videoWriter canAddInput:writerInput]) {
        [videoWriter addInput:writerInput];
    } else {
        // handle error
    }

    [videoWriter startWriting];

    [videoWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];

    CGImageRef img = [image CGImage];

    // Now I am going to create the bixelBuffer
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey,
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey,
                            nil];
    CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;

    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width,
                                          size.height, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                          &pxbuffer);

    if ( !(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL) ) {
        NSLog(@"There be some issue. We didn't get a buffer from the image");
    }


    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, size.width,
                                                 size.height, 8, 4*size.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                                 (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width,
                                           size.height), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);

    // At this point we have our buffer so we are going to start by adding to time zero

    [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:kCMTimeZero];

    while (!writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {} // wait until ready

    CMTime frameTime = CMTimeMake(5, 1); // 5 second frame

    [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:frameTime];
    CFRelease(buffer);

    [writerInput markAsFinished];

    [videoWriter endSessionAtSourceTime:frameTime];

    [videoWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
        if (videoWriter.status != AVAssetWriterStatusCompleted) {
            // Error
        }
    }]; // end videoWriter finishWriting Block

    // NOTE: the URL is actually being returned before the videoWriter finishes writing so be careful to not access it until it's ready
    return outputFile;
}
```

Comment: I am completely grateful for your attempt at my problem with the combination of your Obj-C and Swift code. I have not been able to test this code out, but since I only have 15 hours left and you gave the most in-depth answer, I will choose yours. I appreciate your help! Thank you so much!

Comment: This worked great! But could you explain why I have to add at time Zero and at the end? It makes sense, but why cannot I just add something withPresentationTime?

Comment: I am not entirely sure. My best guess is internally the way it works is that it will show a frame until it has a new frame to replace it. So you have to add it to the beginning to get it to show right away, and then you have to add it to the presentation time to signal the end (so it knows how long to show the first frame). If you only add one frame at the presentation time it will just show that until the video ends and nothing preceding.

Comment: Hey @Gadu, I appreciate your help on this post, and I have another one that is similar to this, if you don't mind helping! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39088313/only-first-track-playing

Answer (score 1):

Here its working for me i hope this is useful to you:-

```
-(void)MixVideo:(NSString *)vidioUrlString withImage:(UIImage *)img
{
    NSURL *videoUrl1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:vidioUrlString];
    AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:videoUrl1 options:nil];

    AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];


    [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    [compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];

    CGSize sizeOfVideo = CGSizeMake(320, 568);

    //Image of watermark
    UIImage *myImage=img;

    CALayer *layerCa = [CALayer layer];

    layerCa.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
    layerCa.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);

    layerCa.opacity = 1.0;

    CALayer *parentLayer=[CALayer layer];

    CALayer *videoLayer=[CALayer layer];

    parentLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);

    videoLayer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfVideo.width, sizeOfVideo.height);
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];

    [parentLayer addSublayer:layerCa];

    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition=[AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition] ;

    videoComposition.frameDuration=CMTimeMake(1, 30);

    videoComposition.renderSize=sizeOfVideo;

    videoComposition.animationTool=[AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];

    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);

    AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

    AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];

    instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];

    videoComposition.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

    finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/myVideo.mp4"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:finalPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:finalPath error:nil];
    }

    SDAVAssetExportSession *encoder = [SDAVAssetExportSession.alloc initWithAsset:mixComposition];
    encoder.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
    encoder.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];
    encoder.videoComposition=videoComposition;
    encoder.videoSettings = @
    {
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: @320,
    AVVideoHeightKey: @568,
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: @
        {
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @900000,
        AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264MainAutoLevel,
        },
    };
    encoder.audioSettings = @
    {
    AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @2,
    AVSampleRateKey: @44100,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey: @128000,
    };

    [encoder exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {

         if (encoder.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
         {

             NSLog(@"Video export succeeded");
             if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(finalPath))
             {

                 NSLog(@"Video exported successfully path = %@ ",finalPath);
             }

         }
         else if (encoder.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled)
         {
             NSLog(@"Video export cancelled");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Video export failed with error: %@ (%ld)", encoder.error.localizedDescription, (long)encoder.error.code);
         }
     }];

}
```

Comment: I have not had time to look at this, but it is in Obj-C and mine is in Swift, so unfortunately I cannot make this answer the correct one, but thanks for your effort and I will definitely transcode to Swift. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try this code use by bridging . Example- create objective c fine .h and .m and put this method in this and access from swift.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 code that should be a good start. If used in production, still needs error handling and handling of video sizing / orientation for some videos.

```
@discardableResult func merge(
    video videoPath: String,
    withForegroundImage foregroundImage: UIImage,
    completion: @escaping (AVAssetExportSession) -> Void) -> AVAssetExportSession {

    let videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
    let videoUrlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoUrl, options: nil)

    // Setup `mutableComposition` from the existing video
    let mutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let videoAssetTrack = videoUrlAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first!
    let videoCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    videoCompositionTrack.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform
    try! videoCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start:kCMTimeZero, duration:videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: videoAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    let audioAssetTrack = videoUrlAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).first!
    let audioCompositionTrack = mutableComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
    try! audioCompositionTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration:audioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration), of: audioAssetTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)

    // Create a `videoComposition` to represent the `foregroundImage`
    let videoSize: CGSize = videoCompositionTrack.naturalSize
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: videoSize.width, height: videoSize.height)
    let imageLayer = CALayer()
    imageLayer.contents = foregroundImage.cgImage
    imageLayer.frame = frame
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = frame
    let animationLayer = CALayer()
    animationLayer.frame = frame
    animationLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    animationLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition(propertiesOf: videoCompositionTrack.asset!)
    videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: animationLayer)

    // Export the video
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.cachesDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first!
    let documentDirectoryUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectory)
    let destinationFilePath = documentDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("video_\(NSUUID().uuidString).mov")
    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession( asset: mutableComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)!
    exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exportSession.outputURL = destinationFilePath
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously { [weak exportSession] in
        if let strongExportSession = exportSession {
            completion(strongExportSession)
        }
    }

    return exportSession
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it works for me, export a single image to a video(the video is movable not static). Swift 3.

```
//
//  CXEImageToAssetURL.swift
//  CXEngine
//
//  Created by wulei on 16/12/14.
//  Copyright © 2016年 wulei. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
import Photos

fileprivate extension UIImage{
    func normalizedImage() -> UIImage?{
//        if self.imageOrientation == .up{
//            return self
//        }
        let factor = CGFloat(0.8)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width:self.size.width * factor, height: self.size.height * factor), false, self.scale)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width * factor, height: self.size.height * factor))
        let normalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return normalImage
    }

//    func clipImage() -> UIImage {

//        var x = CGFloat(0)
//        var y = CGFloat(0)
//        let imageHeight = (self.size.width * 9) / 16
//        y = (self.size.height - imageHeight)/2
//        var rcTmp = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: x, y: y), size: self.size)
//        if self.scale > 1.0 {
//            rcTmp = CGRect(x: rcTmp.origin.x * self.scale, y: rcTmp.origin.y * self.scale, width: rcTmp.size.width * self.scale, height: rcTmp.size.height * self.scale)
//        }
//        rcTmp.size.height = imageHeight
//        let imageRef = self.cgImage!.cropping(to: rcTmp)
//        let result = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
//        return result
//        return self
//    }
}

public typealias CXEImageToVideoProgress = (Float) -> Void
typealias CXEMovieMakerUIImageExtractor = (AnyObject) -> UIImage?


public class CXEImageToVideo: NSObject{

    //MARK: Private Properties

    private var assetWriter:AVAssetWriter!
    private var writeInput:AVAssetWriterInput!
    private var bufferAdapter:AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor!
    private var videoSettings:[String : Any]!
    private var frameTime:CMTime!
    private var fileURL:URL!
    private var duration:Int = 0

    //MARK: Class Method

     private func videoSettingsFunc(width:Int, height:Int) -> [String: Any]{
        if(Int(width) % 16 != 0){
            print("warning: video settings width must be divisible by 16")
        }

        let videoSettings:[String: Any] = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
                                           AVVideoWidthKey: width,
                                           AVVideoHeightKey: height]

        return videoSettings
    }

    //MARK: Public methods

    public init(fileURL: URL, videoWidth:Int, videoHeight:Int) {
        super.init()

        self.videoSettings = videoSettingsFunc(width: videoWidth, height: videoHeight)

        self.fileURL = fileURL
        self.assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(url: self.fileURL, fileType: AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie)

        self.writeInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, outputSettings: videoSettings)
        assert(self.assetWriter.canAdd(self.writeInput), "add failed")

        self.assetWriter.add(self.writeInput)
        let bufferAttributes:[String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB)]
        self.bufferAdapter = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: self.writeInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: bufferAttributes)
        self.frameTime = CMTimeMake(1, 25)
    }

//    public func createMovieFrom(url: URL, duration:Int, progressExtractor: CXEImageToVideoProgress){
//        self.duration = duration
//        self.createMovieFromSource(image: url as AnyObject, extractor:{(inputObject:AnyObject) ->UIImage? in
//            return UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: inputObject as! URL))}, progressExtractor: progressExtractor)
//    }

    public func createMovieFrom(imageData: Data, duration:Int, progressExtractor: CXEImageToVideoProgress){
        var image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        image = image?.normalizedImage()
        assert(image != nil)
        self.duration = duration

        self.createMovieFromSource(image: image!, extractor: {(inputObject:AnyObject) -> UIImage? in
            return inputObject as? UIImage}, progressExtractor: progressExtractor)
    }

    //MARK: Private methods

    private func createMovieFromSource(image: AnyObject, extractor: @escaping CXEMovieMakerUIImageExtractor, progressExtractor: CXEImageToVideoProgress){

        self.assetWriter.startWriting()
        let zeroTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(0),self.frameTime.timescale)
        self.assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: zeroTime)

        while !self.writeInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
            usleep(100)
        }

        var sampleBuffer:CVPixelBuffer?
        var pxDataBuffer:CVPixelBuffer?
        let img = extractor(image)
        assert(img != nil)

        let options:[String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey as String: true, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey as String: true]
        let frameHeight = self.videoSettings[AVVideoHeightKey] as! Int
        let frameWidth = self.videoSettings[AVVideoWidthKey] as! Int
        let originHeight = frameWidth * img!.cgImage!.height / img!.cgImage!.width
        let heightDifference = originHeight - frameHeight

        let frameCounts = self.duration * Int(self.frameTime.timescale)
        let spacingOfHeight = heightDifference / frameCounts

        sampleBuffer = self.newPixelBufferFrom(cgImage: img!.cgImage!)
        assert(sampleBuffer != nil)

        var presentTime = CMTimeMake(1, self.frameTime.timescale)
        var stepRows = 0

        for i in 0..<frameCounts {
            progressExtractor(Float(i) / Float(frameCounts))

            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(sampleBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
            let pointer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(sampleBuffer!)
            var pxData = pointer?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
            let bytes = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(sampleBuffer!) * stepRows
            pxData = pxData?.advanced(by: bytes)

            let status = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, frameWidth, frameHeight, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, pxData!, CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(sampleBuffer!), nil, nil, options as CFDictionary?, &pxDataBuffer)
            assert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxDataBuffer != nil, "newPixelBuffer failed")
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(sampleBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

            while !self.writeInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                usleep(100)
            }
            if (self.writeInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData){
                if i == 0{
                    self.bufferAdapter.append(pxDataBuffer!, withPresentationTime: zeroTime)
                }else{
                    self.bufferAdapter.append(pxDataBuffer!, withPresentationTime: presentTime)
                }
                presentTime = CMTimeAdd(presentTime, self.frameTime)
            }

            stepRows += spacingOfHeight
        }


        self.writeInput.markAsFinished()
        self.assetWriter.finishWriting {}

        var isSuccess:Bool = false
        while(!isSuccess){
            switch self.assetWriter.status {
            case .completed:
                isSuccess = true
                print("completed")
            case .writing:
                usleep(100)
                print("writing")
            case .failed:
                isSuccess = true
                print("failed")
            case .cancelled:
                isSuccess = true
                print("cancelled")
            default:
                isSuccess = true
                print("unknown")
            }
        }
    }

    private func newPixelBufferFrom(cgImage:CGImage) -> CVPixelBuffer?{
        let options:[String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey as String: true, kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey as String: true]
        var pxbuffer:CVPixelBuffer?
        let frameWidth = self.videoSettings[AVVideoWidthKey] as! Int
        let frameHeight = self.videoSettings[AVVideoHeightKey] as! Int

        let originHeight = frameWidth * cgImage.height / cgImage.width

        let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, frameWidth, originHeight, kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, options as CFDictionary?, &pxbuffer)
        assert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != nil, "newPixelBuffer failed")

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer!)
        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let context = CGContext(data: pxdata, width: frameWidth, height: originHeight, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pxbuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue)
        assert(context != nil, "context is nil")

        context!.concatenate(CGAffineTransform.identity)
        context!.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameWidth, height: originHeight))
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        return pxbuffer
    }
}
```