# iOS Swift - PHPhotoLibrary The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)

Tags: avfoundation, swift4, ios11, photosframework, xcode9.2

I'm trying to save a video file to photo library. I got the following code snippet working, but I'm getting weird cocoa error -1 when trying to save a video created using UIImages with text added programmatically.

**What is causing  PHPhotoLibrary error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)" when trying to save a video file?**

happens if I modify the images like this:

```
let midX = image.size.width / 2.0
let imageWithText = image.textToImage(drawText: "Added text", inImage: image, atPoint: CGPoint(x: midX, y: 100))
```

I'm using this solution to add text: [How do I add text to an image in iOS Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift)

```
func textToImage(drawText text: String, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
    let textColor = UIColor.white
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: textFont,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: textColor,
        ] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
 }
```

This code works as long as the image has not been altered by adding text:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: fileURL)
            }) { saved, error in
                if saved {
                   print("Saved video")
                }else if error != nil
                {
                    //getting error -1 here
                    print ("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
```

Comment: The video creation is here, it's rather long. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470154/create-movie-from-uiimage-swift  I've moved the text adding feature to be much earlier, when the photos are captured  and now it works. I'm still not sure what the error -1 is about and am open to suggestions :)

Comment: I still need to be able to add text to image at any point in the app and this problem is still actual