# Save Image with animated gif placed on it

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, gif

I'm creating a instagram like feature, where you can add Draggable text, stickers and gifs.
I am able to add text and stickers and save it by taking a screenshot.

Is there a way to save an image with an animated gif added to it.

Can someone suggest a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify what exactly you trying to achieve and what you struggling with? Do you want to save gif on device? Or just static version of it?

Comment: yes want to save gif on device.not static one.

Comment: @Caleb hi is it still relevant? if so - could you please specify, do you want to use created animations only inside your app, or you want to save it to Photos gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I achieved this using below method,  I hope it helps to someone

1.After placing gif on Image, I am taking screenshot of holderView by this method, using timer.

```
@objc func gifScreenShot() {
      guard let imageView = self.screenView else {
         return
      }

      UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.frame.size, true, 0.0)
      imageView.drawHierarchy(in: imageView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      self.gifImages.append(image!)

      if gifImages.count == 50 {
         self.stopTimer()
      }
   }
```

2.Once 50 screenshot taken, I stop the timer

```
   func stopTimer() {
      if gifTimer != nil {
         gifTimer!.invalidate()
         gifTimer = nil
         DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.createVideo()
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

3.And combine all screenshots to 0.05 secs video and save it photo gallery

```
   func createVideo()  {
      let settings = CXEImagesToVideo.videoSettings(codec: AVVideoCodecType.h264.rawValue, width: (gifImages[0].cgImage?.width)!, height: (gifImages[0].cgImage?.height)!)
      let movieMaker = CXEImagesToVideo(videoSettings: settings)
      movieMaker.createMovieFrom(images: gifImages){ (fileURL:URL) in
         if self.isSaveVideo {
            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
               PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: fileURL)
            }) { saved, error in
               self.loadingViewStop()
               self.gifImages.removeAll()
               if saved {
                  self.gifImages.removeAll()
                  DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     self.view.toastMessage("Video saved successfully".localized)
                  }
               } else {
                  print(error)
               }
            }
         } else {
            self.gifImages.removeAll()
            self.videoFileURL = fileURL
            self.nextTapped(snap: nil)
         }
      }
   }
```

It worked like I expected

Comment: You can find `CXEImagesToVideo` class in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41159403/4442254

Comment: Where the Timer started?