# AVAssetWriter - iOS App - Generating 4K video from 4K image array without losing image size using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avassetwriter

I am trying to create a 4K video from image array of 4K images. Each image size is approximately 5Mb. Images are captured using AVCaptureSession Preset hd4K3840x2160.

As per my assumption, for image array with 4 images, the estimated 4K video output will be approximately 20Mb or more. I am able to create video with h264 codecs from image array as per the following thread -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60149845/14999544

However, the output video gets converted to only 2Mb instead of expected 20Mb.

I did experiment around using proRes(found that it's designed for MacOS), Hevc codecs, changing values for AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey, and updating kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey but no success so far.

Question -
What settings are required on AVAssetWriter to retain the pixels, size of the input image array and generate 4K videos?

Any help would be very much appreciated.