# AVAssetWriterInput and isReadyForMoreMediaData Problem create Video in Swift

Tags: swift, video

I Create Video from Images, Video lost some frame because isReadyForMoreMediaData not ready some time.
When I debug I saw the reason because of the loop, it need some delay time to initiation the next buffer but I don't know how to do that.

```
{
           for nextDicData in self.selectedPhotosArray{      
                if (videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {

                    if let nextImage = nextDicData["img"] as? UIImage
                    {
                        var frameDuration = CMTimeMake(Int64(0), fps)
                        if let timeVl = nextDicData["time"] as? Float{
                               framePerSecond = Int64(timeVl * 1000)
                            print("TIME FRAME : \(timeVl)")

                        }else{
                             framePerSecond = Int64(0.1 * 1000)
                        }

                        frameDuration =  CMTimeMake(framePerSecond ,fps)
                        let lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(lastTimeVl), fps)
                        let presentationTime = CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)
                        var pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer? = nil
                        let status: CVReturn = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer(kCFAllocatorDefault, pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool!, &pixelBuffer)
                        if let pixelBuffer = pixelBuffer, status == 0 {
                            let managedPixelBuffer = pixelBuffer
                            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
                            let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer)
                            let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
                            let context = CGContext(data: data, width: Int(self.outputSize.width), height: Int(self.outputSize.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(managedPixelBuffer), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
                            context!.clear(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(self.outputSize.width), height: CGFloat(self.outputSize.height)))
                            let horizontalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.width) / nextImage.size.width
                            let verticalRatio = CGFloat(self.outputSize.height) / nextImage.size.height
                            //let aspectRatio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFill
                            let aspectRatio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio) // ScaleAspectFit
                            let newSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: nextImage.size.width, height: nextImage.size.height)
                            let x = newSize.width < self.outputSize.width ? (self.outputSize.width - newSize.width) / 2 : 0
                            let y = newSize.height < self.outputSize.height ? (self.outputSize.height - newSize.height) / 2 : 0

                            context?.draw(nextImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
                            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(managedPixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))
                            appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)


                        } else {
                            print("Failed to allocate pixel buffer")
                            appendSucceeded = false
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                    //not ready
                       print("write is Not Raady: \(lastTimeVl)")
                }
                if !appendSucceeded {
                    break
                }
                frameCount += 1
                lastTimeVl += framePerSecond
                print("LAST TIME : \(lastTimeVl)")


            }
```

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883784/build-video-from-uiimage-using-swift>
i hope it will work.

Comment: thanks but not my problem

Answer (score 2):

The `AVAssetWriterInput` can help you manage it and let you know when `isReadyForMoreMediaData` is `true` again, by calling `requestMediaDataWhenReady`.

Here is an example from apple documentation (translated to Swift):

```
myAVAssetWriterInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: queue) {
    while myAVAssetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        let nextSampleBuffer = copyNextSampleBufferToWrite()
        if let nextSampleBuffer = nextSampleBuffer { 
            // you have another frame to add
            myAVAssetWriterInput.append(nextSampleBuffer)
        } else { 
            // finished to add frames
            myAVAssetWriterInput.markAsFinished()
            break
        }
    }
})
```

Now, when the writer gets not ready "suddenly", no worries,
it will continue adding frames on the next requestMediaDataWhenReady callback.

Answer (score -2):

**swift 5**

Add usleep after pixelBufferAdaptor.append.

Reason for adding sleep function is that when there are multiple inputs, AVAssetWriter tries to write media data in an **interleaving pattern**, so writer must be ready for next input(image in your case) in order to append data. Waiting for some time makes it ready for next input.[link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetwriterinput)

```
 appendSucceeded = pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
 //VideoWriterInput must be paused for atleast 50 milliseconds or the buffer wont be ready to append new frame
 usleep(useconds_t(50000) )
```