# Add animated overlay to UIImage and save as video to camera roll

Tags: swift, animation, uiimage, watermark

So I know how to add an animated overlay to a video using layers, AVMutableVideoComposition(), and instructions. How can I add an animated overlay to a still UIImage and export it as a video (similar to how a Snapchat or Instagram story animated overlay works)? Should I be converting the image to a video first and then adding overlays, or is there an easier way?

Comment: I did something like this but what I did was , I added image over video, you can try that

Comment: I need to do the opposite. Animation over image. I know how to do image over video

Comment: go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883784/build-video-from-uiimage-using-swift , what I can think of now is convert image into video and merge both

Comment: @ShivamGaur That is what I ended up doing. I am now having the problem where adding the overlay is killing the video quality. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57211035/avassetexportsession-is-greatly-reducing-video-quality?noredirect=1#comment100929551_57211035