# Overlaying image on video reduces video resolution

Tags: swift, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition, avvideocomposition

When I overlay an image on my video, the video quality is greatly reduced. If I don't set the video composition of the export session or set the export quality to passthrough, the video quality is great (but I get no overlays obviously).

I'm passing in a local .mov video url to add the overlays too.
I'm using PHPhotoLibrary to save the video to the camera roll.
Using some other functions to transform the video and set its instructions.

It all seems pretty straightforward, but something is killing the video quality

```
func merge3(url: URL) {

    let firstAsset = AVAsset(url: url)

    // 1 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

    // 2 - Create two video tracks
    guard
      let firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                      preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
      else {
        return
    }
    do {
      try firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: firstAsset.duration),
                                     of: firstAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0],
                                     at: CMTime.zero)
    } catch {
      print("Failed to load first track")
      return
    }

    let s = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let imglogo = UIImage(named: "django")?.scaleImageToSize(newSize: CGSize(width: 250, height: 125))
    let imglayer = CALayer()
    imglayer.contents = imglogo?.cgImage
    imglayer.frame = CGRect(x: s.width / 2 - 125, y: s.height / 2 - 67.5
      , width: 250, height: 125)
    imglayer.opacity = 1.0

    let videolayer = CALayer()
    videolayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: s.width, height: s.height)

    let parentlayer = CALayer()
    parentlayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: s.width, height: s.height)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(videolayer)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(imglayer)

    // 2.1
    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero,
                                                duration: firstAsset.duration)

    let layercomposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    layercomposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    layercomposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videolayer, in: parentlayer)
    layercomposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

    // instruction for watermark
    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: firstAsset.duration)
    _ = mixComposition.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0] as AVAssetTrack
    let layerinstruction = VideoHelper.videoCompositionInstruction1(firstTrack, asset: firstAsset)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [layerinstruction]
    layercomposition.instructions = [instruction]

    // 4 - Get path
    guard let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                           in: .userDomainMask).first else {
                                                            return
    }
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
    let url = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(date).mov")

    // 5 - Create Exporter
    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition,
                                              presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
                                                return
    }
    exporter.outputURL = url
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileType.mov
    exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter.videoComposition = layercomposition

    // 6 - Perform the Export
    exporter.exportAsynchronously() {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.exportDidFinish(exporter)
      }
    }
  }
```

```
func exportDidFinish(_ session: AVAssetExportSession) {

    guard
      session.status == AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed,
      let outputURL = session.outputURL
      else {
        return
    }

    let saveVideoToPhotos = {
      PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: outputURL)
      }) { saved, error in
        let success = saved && (error == nil)
        let title = success ? "Success" : "Error"
        let message = success ? "Video saved" : "Failed to save video"

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
    }

    // Ensure permission to access Photo Library
    if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != .authorized {
      PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
        if status == .authorized {
          saveVideoToPhotos()
        }
      }
    } else {
      saveVideoToPhotos()
    }
  }
```

```
static func videoCompositionInstruction1(_ track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset)
    -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {
      let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
      let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video)[0]

      let transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
      let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform)

      var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width
      if assetInfo.isPortrait { // not hit
        scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
        instruction.setTransform(assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor), at: CMTime.zero)
      } else { // hit
        let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scaleToFitRatio, y: scaleToFitRatio)
        var concat = assetTrack.preferredTransform.concatenating(scaleFactor)
          .concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4))
        if assetInfo.orientation == .down { // not hit
          let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
          let windowBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
          let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
          let centerFix = CGAffineTransform(translationX: assetTrack.naturalSize.width, y: yFix)
          concat = fixUpsideDown.concatenating(centerFix).concatenating(scaleFactor)
        }
        instruction.setTransform(concat, at: CMTime.zero)
      }

      return instruction
  }
```

```
static func orientationFromTransform(_ transform: CGAffineTransform)
    -> (orientation: UIImage.Orientation, isPortrait: Bool) {
      var assetOrientation = UIImage.Orientation.up
      var isPortrait = false
      if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .right
        isPortrait = true
      } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
        assetOrientation = .left
        isPortrait = true
      } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .up
      } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
        assetOrientation = .down
      }
      return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
  }
```

Comment: Not entirely sure - but have you attempted using `videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(someWidth, someHeight)` for your `AVAssetExportSession`. What also may be happening is the resolution of your .mov may be taking over - what is that? Also, if neither of those help, could we get the data as to exactly what your resolution was for both the first/second videos and then the final video?

Comment: @impression7vx I will grab those resolutions, but aren't I setting the render size for the videoComposition when I set layercomposition.renderSize to the Screen bounds

Comment: @impression7vx Ah. Resolution is being cut. Original video resolution is 900x1200 and exported vid is 414x736. Will start digging into what is cutting it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: I know your problem! Posting solution hahahaha one moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your

```
layercomposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
```

when it should be

```
layercomposition.renderSize = yourAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0].naturalSize
```

What the first one does is set your resolution to your screen size and not the actual size of the original video. The 2nd one corrects it to setting the resolution of the original video.

Think of it this way - you don't want your resolution to be the size of your screen - that would be really small. You want it the size of some original video or the size of some commonly used video setting.

Comment: This is causing the video layer to be super tiny

Comment: I'm assuming my transformation somewhere are causing the video to become tiny. Because the bigger I render the video, the smaller the video becomes which is weird

Comment: Never did overlays but this will give you the correct resolution of the initial asset. Whatever transforms you do to your initial video and how it affects the size, get that ratio and multiply it by this size.

Comment: You are a hero among peasants my friend. Thank you

Comment: Haha. Just experience with AVAssets a little bit :)

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't fix the issue I have. The naturalSize and the size I was picking were the same. Adding the overlay still reduces the quality.

Comment: @christophercotton then you have a diff type of problem. Do you have a question related to your code. If so, link the SO question here

Comment: @impression7vx Hey mate, can you guide me here please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575445/avexportsession-add-uiview-with-gifs-and-drawings-on-a-video

Comment: I’ll take a look sometime this weekend