# Capture multiple frames and prepare a video like boomerang

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am trying to integrate a functionality where i have to capture multiple frames let say 3 frames in a second and at last combines all captured frames to form a video and upload that video on server.

You can refer the functionality same as happens in boomerang, i have searched a lot about the most effective way to do the same but didn't found anything helpful.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Video From Image Array

For combining your image array to video please make use of widely accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742212/5215474).

> By using AVAssetWriter and CVPixelBufferRef .

### To Make Video in reverse order

This can be done effectively Using the `AVFoundation` library.

Use `AVAssetReader` to read the video and Use `AVAssetWriter` to write the video in reverse order.

Refer the tutorial [Reverse Video AVFoundation](http://www.andyhin.com/post/5/reverse-video-avfoundation)

Comment: i have array of images captured within specific intervals now i have to generate a video out of it., i dont have a video .