# CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage returns -6660 on macOS 10.13

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal

I'm recording the screen from my iPhone device to my Mac. As a preview layer, I am collecting sample buffers directly from an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, from which I'm creating textures and rendering them with `Metal`. The problem I'm having is that code that worked in macOS prior to `10.13` stopped working after updating to `10.13`. Namely,

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(_currentSampleBuffer);

if (!imageBuffer) return;

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

CVMetalTextureRef metalTexture = NULL;
CVReturn result = CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(nil,
                                                            self.textureCache,
                                                            imageBuffer,
                                                            nil,
                                                            self.pixelFormat,
                                                            width,
                                                            height,
                                                            0,
                                                            &metalTexture);

if (result == kCVReturnSuccess) {
    self.texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(metalTexture);
}
```

Returns `result = -6660`, which translates to a generic `kCVReturnError`, as can be seen [on the official Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1572713-result_codes?language=objc), and the `metalTexture = NULL`.

The pixel format I'm using is `MTLPixelFormatBGRG422` since the samples coming from the camera are `2vuy`.

As a workaround to creating `metalTexture` from `sampleBuffer`, I am now
creating an intermediate `NSImage` like so:

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(_currentSampleBuffer);
NSCIImageRep *imageRep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:imageBuffer]];
    
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[imageRep size]];
[image addRepresentation:imageRep];
```

and creating a `MTLTexture` from that. That is obviously a subpar solution to using `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` directly.

Once again, the code in question works perfectly fine in `macOS < 10.13`, I'd like to know if anyone has similar issues, and if so, do you have any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've come across the same issue, the problem was not asking for Metal compatibility when configuring the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. I guess the system started to check this in macOS 10.13, possibly to apply some optimization when not requested.

The solution was to add the `kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey` to the `videoSettings` property of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.

In Objective-C:

```
outputCapture.videoSettings = @{
  /* ... */
  (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey: @YES
};
```

In Swift:

```
outputCapture.videoSettings = [
  /* ... */
  kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey as String: true
]
```

I think this warrants a radar, to ask Apple to at least print a warning message when this occurs. I'll update this if I get to it.

Comment: awesome, this works! I need to check the output format in the pixel buffer now though since I'm getting a split image and strange colors. I'll post my workaround in another answer for future reference.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me as it also applies if you are making your own CVPixelBuffer with:  `CVPixelBufferCreate` by adding to your attributes dictionary: `let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferMetalCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue, ...<others>... ] as CFDictionary`

Comment: This doesn't work if you've created your cvpixelbuffer using `CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes` or `CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes` as specified in this technical note; https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1781/_index.html  Setting the key has no effect.

Comment: EliaCereda thank u, it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this, which keeps the `2vuy` format in the pixel buffer, but the bad thing is that you make a copy of the pixel buffer data which affects performance. I'm posting this for future reference, or if anyone else finds it useful. Basically we intercept the pixel buffer and then add attributes while copying the data.

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                             @"IOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibility": @YES
                             };
CVPixelBufferRef copy = NULL;

CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                    CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer),
                    CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer),
                    CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(pixelBuffer),
                    (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes,
                    &copy);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(copy, 0);

void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
void *copyBaseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(copy);

memcpy(copyBaseAddress, baseAddress, CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(pixelBuffer));

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(copy, 0);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get from a `CVPixelBufferRef` to a Metal texture, you could go via a `CIImage` and use a `CIContext` with a Metal device (hopefully minimises getting the CPU involved with copying the pixel buffer);

Make sure your target metal texture is appropriately sized.

```
CIContext* ciContext = [CIContext contextWithMTLDevice:mtlDevice
    options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@(NO),kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer,nil]
];

id<MTLCommandBuffer> metalCommandBuffer=[mtlCommandQueue commandBufferWithUnretainedReferences];

CIImage* ciImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:cvPixelBuffer];

[ciContext render:ciImage 
    toMTLTexture:metal_texture 
    commandBuffer:mtlCommandBuffer
    bounds:[ciImage extent])
    colorSpace:[ciImage colorSpace]];
```