# How to load an array with hundreds of UIImage instances without crashing the app because of the memory surge?

Tags: ios, uiimage, avfoundation, cakeyframeanimation

I have an animation which consists of 250 frames. Each frame is 1080x1920 resolution and in PNG format. I need to take all these frames, animate them with `CAKeyframeAnimation` and render them on a video using `AVFoundation` tools.

The issue arises when I try to create a `values` array for `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Initializing 250 FullHD images causes quite a big memory spike, which system detects and decides to kill the app.
I've tried playing with `autoreleasepool` but it doesn't seem to help at all (no wonder, because `CAKeyframeAnimation` needs to hold on those images).

The problem goes even further: I actually have 10 of such animations! And I need to quickly switch between them because the app allows to preview those animations dynamically (which is done via `AVSynchronizedLayer`) before exporting everything in a video file.

So my question is: how can I load a big array of `UIImage` instances without  system killing the app because of a memory surge? Is there an asynchronous way of loading them?

Answer (score 2):

> how can I load a big array of UIImage instances without system killing the app because of a memory surge?

You can't. What you're trying to do is wrong from the outset.

- If the goal is to make a "sprite animation" by using keyframe animation to change a layer's content periodically, the animation should consist of a *small* number of *small* images.
- If the goal is to make a video based on a succession of images, a keyframe animation is not how to do it in the first place.

Comment: For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie. But do _not_ follow its advice to form a `[UIImage]`! Form an array of image _names_ and load just _one_ image at a time, as needed, using care not to cache the image as you load it. The ImageIO framework gives you the tools to do that.

Comment: The goal is to make a "sprite animation" by using keyframe animation and render that animation real-time on a FullHD video (with an option to then export that video). Sacrificing animation duration by reducing frames amount or reducing image quality is not an option, so I guess I'll have to dig into some other options. Anyway, thank you for your help!