# UIImage to movie using metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I know how to export UIImage array as a movie using swift. But it takes a lot of time. I am following this thread [How do I export UIImage array as a movie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie)

Is there any way to reduce export time? I am trying to export UIImage array as movie using metal to check if it can reduce export time. But I am not getting any resource to do that. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used [MTTransitions](https://github.com/alexiscn/MTTransitions). But it is not so fast and also has memory issue.