# Programmatically make video from UIImages for playback with MPMovie Player

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can I programmatically create a video file from a bunch of UIImages?

I want to do this so I can play back a slideshow with MPMoviePlayer and stream via AirPlay.

Ideally I'd like to be able to set a duration for each image and do simple fade transitions between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [AVAssetWriter documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for encoding your own movies on an iOS device.

Another hint might be this question on SO: [How do I use AVAssetWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728311/how-do-i-use-avassetwriter)