# Can I create a blue-screen effect with MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, image-processing, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am showing a video inline (not fullscreen) using MPMoviePlayerController. I am using this class because it is the only player I got working using a remote file (progressive download) and not a local file.

Is there any way to create a blue-screen effect? what I basically mean is decide on a certain RGB value and set that pixel's alpha to 0. Is it possible to perform any image processing per frame with MPMoviePlayerController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use MPMoviePlayerController for such movie processing.

Still, there is ways to accomplish what you are asking for. You may use the AVAssetWriter etc.

Check my answer on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246419/programmatically-make-video-from-uiimages-for-playback-with-mpmovie-player/6318700#6318700).